# Safe to share geths chaindata folder?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

As many people have quite a hard time syncing their wallets to even get started with Ethereum I offer my `chaindata` folder as a regular dump (`.tar.gz`). Downloading a dump is in most cases way faster than syncing from scratch. I have heard of people waiting for a sync for two weeks straight.

Is this secure for me or do I expose secrets of my wallet doing this / do I risk being hacked?

(This should not be a debate about if you can trust my or other peoples chaindata dump.)

**EDIT:**

For the ones interested in downloading a recent copy of the Ethereum chain, feel free to grab a copy from [https://dl.ender.io/eth-chain/](https://goo.gl/Ei5vV4)

After downloading make sure to check the sha256 sum, stop geth / Ethereum wallet and replace your `chaindata` folder with the one from my archive. After that start geth / your Ethereum wallet again and let it sync the remaining blocks. This should be a lot faster than a clean sync.

(Please make a backup of your private keys first in case you delete something that's wrong!)

- Who am I?

Just some German guy that wants to help people out by hosting current copies of the chain on a German server.

- Can you talk to me?

Sure just write me here or send me a message!

Comment: Hi there. Is it _your_ server? If so, you've just advertised its existence to the world on a public forum :-) Regardless of whether your keys are safe while other people are downloading the chaindata, have you performed any sort of general security audit? :-)

Comment: Yes this is *my* server. Exposing its existence to the world is not harming anything as all public IP ranges are scanned 24/7/365 anyways ;)

The server is secured following securities best practices and 5 years of experience. I cannot go deeper into *what* has exactly been done to secure things. I hope you can understand.

EDIT: It is also audited 24/7 of course.

Answer (score 2):

Safe for you for not for them. How do they know the chain data you supplied is trustworthy?

Comment: Yeah that's up to *them*. Like anywhere in the world 50/50 if you are thrown over or if you can trust a person. Thanks for the answer. The trust questions is aside the point.

I was just curious if there is anything in there linking to me or exposing my data in any way.

Comment: Nothing not already exposed on the blockchain. Your secrets are in the keystore folder. Chaindata is common to all users following the same chain.

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain data are just a record of all the transactions done in the ethereum blockchain. So the `geth export` command (that just export the blockchain data) don't export your private key whatsoever. So don't worry about your wallet security.

It's a nice idea to take the chaindata folder of the trustworthy person to make your geth client synchronize faster, you just have to be sure it's the right ethereum blockchain.

Comment: I directly upload the `chaindata` folder because even `geth export` is fast `geth import` takes equally long than downloading it directly. While extracting the complete folder is way faster.